# recursively unfold function with univ predicate

Tags: recursion, prolog, substitution

I want to replace for example a with 2 in this term `f(a,b,g(a,h(a)))`.

For this I first wanna unfold this term with the univ predicate `=..`.

So far I have:

```
unfold(T1, T2) :-
    T1 =.. T1list,
    T2 = T1list.
```

which is true when T2 is the list represantation of T1.
But in this example I need a way to do this recursively because some arguments are functions as well!
After substitution I need to do all the way back to get `f(2,b,g(2,h(2)))` as an example

for the substitution I have

```
replace(X,Y,[],[]).
replace(X,Y,[X|T1],[Y|T2]):-
     replace(X,Y,T1,T2).
replace(X,Y,[H|T1],[H|T2]):-
     not(X=H),
     replace(X,Y,T1,T2).
```

EDIT: My current Solution: my problem is, it does not work for
`replace(a, 1, X, f(1,b,g(1,h(1)))).`

```
replace(_, _, [], []). 
replace(X, Y, L1, L2) :-
    not(is_list(L1)),
    not(is_list(L2)),
    unfold(L1, L1unfold),
    replace(X,Y, L1unfold, L2sub),
    refold(L2sub, L2),
    !.
replace(X, Y, [X|T1], [Y|T2]) :-
    replace(X, Y, T1, T2),
    !.
replace(X, Y, [H|T1], [H|T2]) :-
    \+ is_list(H),
    replace(X, Y, T1, T2),
    !.
replace(X, Y, [H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
    replace(X, Y, H1, H2),
    replace(X, Y, T1, T2).

unfold(T1, [H|T2]) :-
  T1 =.. [H|T1Expanded],
  maplist(unfold, T1Expanded, T2).

refold([H|T2],T1):-
  maplist(refold,T2,R),
  T1 =.. [H|R].
```

Comment: Your `replace` currently only works on a 'flat' list, whereas it will need to work on embedded lists. `f(a,b,g(a,h(a)))` will unfold into `[f,[a],[b],[g,[a],[h,[a]]]]`.

Answer (score 1):

You're surprisingly close.

```
unfold(T1, [H|T2]) :-
  T1 =.. [H|T1Expanded],
  maplist(unfold, T1Expanded, T2).
```

Comment: nice! and back, with the mirrored `refold([H|T2],T1):- maplist(refold,T2,R), T1 =.. [H|R].` now the OP really can deep-substitute `2`s for `a`s in their nested terms... just must be careful *not* to replace the *first* elements in non-singleton lists.